# Several Swiper sliders on same Angular app/component?

Tags: javascript, angular, swiper.js

I using [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/api/) to add sliders to my Angular (7) app.

The problem is that I don't manage to have separate sliders on the same app, even if not in the same component.

The Swiper doc tells this, when you are using it with vanilla JS:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  speed: 400,
  spaceBetween: 100
});
```

In my Angular app, I have this in the .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductItemVM } from 'src/app/models/product/product-item-vm';
import { SwiperConfigInterface } from 'ngx-swiper-wrapper';

@Component({
  selector: 'srp-product-carousel-container',
  templateUrl: './product-carousel-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-carousel-container.component.scss']
})

export class ProductCarouselContainerComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() productList: ProductItemVM[];

public config: SwiperConfigInterface = {
direction: 'horizontal',
threshold: 0,
spaceBetween: 20,
slidesPerView: 1,
keyboard: true,
mousewheel: false,
scrollbar: false,
navigation: true,
pagination: true
};

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Here is the [doc for Angular wrapper of Swiper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-swiper-wrapper).

I can't declare a new slider, and so I can't call another swiper-container class to aim different sliders.

Does somebody ever had this problem and found a way to solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: How are you using it in your component? A stackblitz example would be great to understand your problem

Comment: @Kenny I have updated the content of my ts file. I have nothing more in it.
And in the html, it is standard Swiper with container, wrapper, prev, next...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can have multiple sliders on the same page or component using **ngx-swiper-wrapper**

If we want to add 2 carousals/sliders - one for testimonials and another for gallery, then we need to create 2 separate configs

```
    import { SwiperConfigInterface } from 'ngx-swiper-wrapper';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: './home.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
    })

    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }

      gallery_config: SwiperConfigInterface = {
            direction: 'horizontal',
            slidesPerView: 1,
            allowTouchMove: true,
            pagination:{el:'.swiper-pagination',clickable:true},
            autoplay: {
              delay: 3000,
              disableOnInteraction: true
            }
      };
        
      testimonial_config: SwiperConfigInterface = {
            direction: 'horizontal',
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 40,
            allowTouchMove: true,
            scrollbar:true
      };
```

Now add the config's to its respective swiper-container.

Add gallery_config to one swiper-container

```
<div  class="swiper-container" [swiper]="gallery_config" >
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div  class="swiper-slide">
             ...
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Add testimonial_config to another swiper-container

```
 <div  class="swiper-container" [swiper]="testimonial_config" >
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div  class="swiper-slide">
                 ...
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
```

If you have more swiper-container's then you can create more config's with different names and assign that to them if each has different swiper styles

Comment: ngx-swiper-wrapper was not updated for ages...